# NetBeans PHP; quick require/include file popup

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

Quick one -- In NetBeans (*running 7.0.1*) while working on a PHP project, the `require`/`include` constructs have a nice auto-complete feature where you can select a path relative to the current file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> like so:

[image]

What would be necessary to get NetBeans to support such a popup for another function or construct? I have a few `include`/`require` wrapper functions and development efforts would be aided by availability of this feature in that context.

Answer (score 0):

You could use code templates

Go to: tools -> options -> editor -> code templates

Then PHP as the language. Click "new", then give the template a shortcut (abbreviation).

Now if you go back to the editor, type the shortcut, then press tab it will complete it for you.

Also note there are various tokens to place your cursor, and make selections etc like `${selection}` and `${cursor}` (see the other code templates for examples)

Also another good trick (you may, or may not know about) is: press `[ALT]+[Insert]` to bring up the code generation dialog. And you can also press `[CTRL]+[SPACE]` to bring the code completion drop down up. It has various other other completions when you do it inside a class that don't normally popup automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Petah -- I use `Ctrl` + `Space` consistently, as is how to open said popup. As far as code templates go, I don't see how I could use them to indicate to NetBeans I want a file-relative path selection popup.